# How to use temporary table in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have created temporary table and would like to use it in place of CASE statement in my stored procedure. Let me know how can I do it in order to write readable code and performance improvement.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_FreeMealsIndicator(STFM_LearnFAMCode char(3) NULL)
    INSERT INTO #Table_FreeMealsIndicator
    SELECT
    CASE WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=1 THEN '14-15 year old learner is eligible for free meals' WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=2 THEN '16-19 year old learner is eligible for and in receipt of free meals'
    ELSE 'N/A' END AS FreeMealsIndicator
    FROM sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt rg
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID AND STEN_Provision_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code AND STEN_Provision_Instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM ON STFM_Year = STEN_Year AND STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID
```

Stored Proc:

```
Use [Reporting]

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_WarehouseAttendance_New]

    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        ---------delete existing warehouse table------------------------------
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New; 
    --------Create New Table--------------------------------------------------
    ---Weeks--------------------------------------------------------------------
    With weeks as 
    (select VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year, min(VDC_day_date) as WeekCommence
    from sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
    where VDC_avail = 'T'
    group by VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year),

    ---TTWeeks------------------------------------------------------------------
    TTWeeks as

    (SELECT VDC_Cal_Year as REMSYear, [VDC_week_no] as WholeYearWeekNo, WeekCommence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year ORDER BY VDC_week_no) as TermTimeWeekNo
    FROM weeks)

    ---Main---------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT    

    s.STYR_Primary_Programme AS PrimaryProgramme, 
    CASE WHEN s.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416' WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+' END AgeBand,
    rg.REGT_Year, 
    RTRIM(ph.PRPH_ML1) AS PRPH_ML1, 
    q.GNCD_Description AS [Curriculum Area], 
    RTRIM(ph.PRPH_ML2) AS Section, 
    q.GNCD_Description AS Section_Name, 
    lEFT(q.GNCD_Description, 3) AS Dept, 
    RTRIM(rg.REGT_Provision_Code) as REGT_Provision_Code, 
    RTRIM(ph.PRPH_Title) as PRPH_Title, 
    rg.REGT_Student_ID, STEN_Student_ID, STEN_Funding_Stream,  
    rs.REGS_Session_No, 
    RTRIM(rh.REGH_Class_Register) as Class_Register, 
    RTRIM(rh.REGH_Register_Title) as Register_Title, 
    CASE WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '1' THEN 'Sunday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '2' THEN 'Monday' 
    WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '3' THEN 'Tuesday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '5' THEN 'Thursday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '6' THEN 'Friday' 
    WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '7' THEN 'Saturday' END AS Register_Day, 
    rh.[REGH_Start_Time] as StartTime, rh.[REGH_End_Time] as EndTime,
        CASE WHEN (rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '27%' 
    OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'FS%') 
    THEN 'FunctionalSkill' 
    WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '16%' THEN 'GCSE' 
    WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/F%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/D%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/E%' OR
    rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/X%' THEN 'Main' ELSE 'Addition' END AS CourseType, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(ra.RGAT_Present,'X') IN ('N', 'Y','X') and rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE()
    THEN rs.REGS_Duration - ISNULL(rd.REGD_Mins_Late,0) ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Poss, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(ra.RGAT_Present,'X') = 'Y' AND 
    rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
    rs.REGS_Duration - rd.REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Att, 
    CASE WHEN ra.RGAT_Present = 'Y' AND rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
    rd.REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Late, 
    rs.[REGS_Session_Date] as Session_Date, TermTimeWeekNo,
    rh.REGH_ISN, ph.PRPH_ISN, st.STUD_Surname, st.STUD_Forename_1, rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark,
    rg.REGT_start_date, rg.REGT_End_date, WeekCommence,
    STFM_LearnFAMCode,
    CASE 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=1 THEN '14-15 year old learner is eligible for free meals'
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=2 THEN '16-19 year old learner is eligible for and in receipt of free meals'
    ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS FreeMealsIndicator,
    CASE 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=36   THEN 'Care to Learn (C2L) (EFA funded only)'
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=55   THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner member of a vulnerable group (EFA funded only)'  
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=56   THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded discretionary bursary (EFA funded only)' 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=57   THEN 'Residential support (EFA funded only)'
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=58   THEN '19+ Hardship (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'    
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=59   THEN '20+ Childcare (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'   
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode=60   THEN 'Residential Access Fund (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)' 
    WHEN STFM_LearnFAMCode IN (61, 62, 63, 64, 65) THEN 'Unassigned'    
    ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS Bursary, 
    CASE 
    WHEN st.STUD_Gender='M' THEN 'Male'
    WHEN st.STUD_Gender='F' THEN 'Female'
    END AS Gender, 
    CASE 
    WHEN st.STUD_Ethnicity= 31 THEN 'White - English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British'
    WHEN st.STUD_Ethnicity= 32 THEN 'White - Irish'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 33 THEN 'White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 34 THEN 'White - Any Other White background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 35 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black Caribbean'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 36 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black African'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 37 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Asian'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 38 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - Any Other Mixed / multiple ethnic background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 39 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Indian'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 40 THEN 'Asian/ Asian British - Pakistani'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 41 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 42 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Chinese'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 43 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Any other Asian background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 44 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - African'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 45 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Caribbean'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 46 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Any other Black / African / Caribbean background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 47 THEN 'Other ethnic group - Arab'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 98 THEN 'Any Other'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 99 THEN 'Not provided'
    END AS Ethnicity,
    CASE 
    WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 1 THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 0 THEN 'No'
    END AS [Looked After Child],
    CASE 
    WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type = 'STYR' THEN 'Yes'
    WHEN SUB1.GNUC_Type != 'STYR' THEN 'No'
    END AS ALS

    INTO dbo.WarehouseAttendance_New   

    FROM        
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt rg
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGSrgsessn rs ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rs.REGS_REGH_ISN  
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
    ON rs.REGS_Session_Date=VDC_day_date 
    INNER JOIN TTWeeks on rg.REGT_year=TTWeeks.REMSYear
    and VDC_week_no=WholeYearWeekNo and VDC_cal_year=REMSYear
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGHrghdr rh ON rh.REGH_ISN = rg.REGT_REGH_ISN 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader ph ON rg.REGT_Provision_Code = ph.PRPH_Code 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes AS ML2 ON ML2.GNCD_General_Code = PRPH_ML2 AND ML2.GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2' 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID AND STEN_Provision_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code AND
    STEN_Provision_Instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM ON STFM_Year = STEN_Year AND STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.STYRstudentYR s ON s.STYR_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID AND s.STYR_Year = rg.REGT_Year   
    INNER JOIN (SELECT GNUC_Type, GNUC_Year, GNUC_Entity_ISN FROM sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom 
    WHERE (GNUC_Year IN ('2013', '2014', '2015'))) AS SUB1 ON rg.REGT_Year = SUB1.GNUC_Year 
    -- AND STYR_ISN = SUB1.GNUC_Entity_ISN
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     ACYR_College_Year
    FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.ACYR
    WHERE      (ACYR_College_Year in (2015, 2014, 2013, 2012))) AS SUB ON REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STUDStudent st on s.STYR_Student_ID=st.STUD_Student_ID
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom g ON STUD_ISN = g.GNUC_Entity_ISN AND g.GNUC_Type = 'STUD'       
    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGDropin rd ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rd.REGD_REGH_ISN AND rg.REGT_Student_ID = rd.REGD_Student_ID 
    AND rd.REGD_Session_No = rs.REGS_Session_No
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance ra ON rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark = ra.RGAT_Attendance_Code 
    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit ON pit.PRPI_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code 
    and pit.prpi_instance = REGT_Provision_Instance
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     GNCD_General_Code, GNCD_Description
    FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes
    WHERE      (GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2')) AS q ON q.GNCD_General_Code =  RTrim(PRPH_ML2) 
    COMMIT
    END

    GO
```

Comment: Instead of a temporary table, you should really make a normal table that contains the descriptions for your codes

Comment: Check your create and insert statements for that `#Table_FreeMealsIndicator`: you create a `char(3)` column where you want to insert a long description. Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: Yes only error I get is this: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 6
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: That is because you are trying to put data that won't fit into a char(3) column.  Increase the size of that column to match the data you are trying to insert.  At the same time, what makes you think inserting into a temp table with improve performance and readability?